# Yii2 - Key Value Not Working

Tags: yii2

I want to relate to a model from another model, but I got this error:

[image: Composite key]

This is the other model I am pointing to from the View

**CourseMaster Model**

```
    public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('course', 'ID'),
        'course_code' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Code'),
        'course_type' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Type'),
        'course_title' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Title'),
        'course_unit' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Unit'),           
    ];
}

 function getCourseCodes()
 {
    return ($this->course_code);
 }     

 function getCourseTitles()
 {
    return ($this->course_title);
 }   

 function getCourseTypes()
 {
    return ($this->course_type);
 }          

 function getCourseUnits()
 {
    return ($this->course_unit);
 }
```

This is the Main Model that I want to display in the view

**CourseRegistrationDetail Model**

```
    public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => Yii::t('course', 'ID'),
        'course_registration_id' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Registration'),
        'course_id' => Yii::t('course', 'Course Title'),
        'student_id' => Yii::t('course', 'Student'),
        'remark' => Yii::t('course', 'Remark'),

    ];
}

public function getCourseMaster()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CourseMaster::className(), ['id' => 'course_id']);
}
```

I want to be able to use array index as $key

**View**

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan=3 class="padding-left padding-right"> 
                <?php $totalUnit = 0; 
                $courseRegistrationDetails = \app\modules\course\models\CourseRegistrationDetail::find()->where(['course_registration_id' => $model->id])->asArray()->all(); ?>
                <table border="1" class="table table-border" style="width:100%;">
   <tr class="header">
    <th><?php echo Yii::t('report', 'SI.No'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo Yii::t('report', 'Course Code'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo Yii::t('report', 'Course Title'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo Yii::t('report', 'Course Type'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo Yii::t('report', 'Unit'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo Yii::t('report', 'Remark'); ?></th>                                
   </tr> 
   <?php 
   foreach($courseRegistrationDetails as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.($key+1).'</td>'; 
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$value->courseMasters->courseCodes.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$value->courseMasters->courseTitles.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$value->courseMasters->courseTypes.'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$value->courseMasters->courseUnits.'</td>';   
                                echo '<td class="text-center">'.$value['remark'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $totalUnit+=$value['course_unit'];
   }
   ?>    
   <tr>
    <th class="text-right border-hide padding-right" colspan=4><?php echo Yii::t('report', 'Total Unit'); ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $totalUnit; ?></th>
   </tr>                        
                </table>    
  </td>
 </tr>
```

How do I resolve the error and use array index as $key

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is exactly but it looks like $value->courseMasters might be returning null? $courseRegistrationDetails is an array and $key and $value look like they should be correctly populated.

Comment: Your relation name is `courseMaster` not `courseMasters`. Secondary you have used `asArray()` in query, so cannot access object or relation that way.

Comment: if you are using `asArray()`in query try `$value['courseMasters']['courseCodes']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query**

```
$courseRegistrationDetails = \app\modules\course\models\CourseRegistrationDetail::find()
    ->with('courseMaster')
    ->where(['course_registration_id' => $model->id])
    ->all();
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($courseRegistrationDetails as $key => $value) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= ($key + 1) ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value->courseMaster->courseCodes ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value->courseMaster->courseTitles ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value->courseMaster->courseTypes ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value->courseMaster->courseUnits ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value->remark ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $totalUnit += $value->course_unit; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Using asArray()**

**Query**

```
$courseRegistrationDetails = \app\modules\course\models\CourseRegistrationDetail::find()
    ->with('courseMaster')
    ->where(['course_registration_id' => $model->id])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($courseRegistrationDetails as $key => $value) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= ($key + 1) ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value['courseMaster']['course_code'] ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value['courseMaster']['course_title'] ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value['courseMaster']['course_type'] ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value['courseMaster']['course_unit'] ?> </td>
        <td class="text-center"> <?= $value['remark'] ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $totalUnit += $value['course_unit']; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```